# Regression model not fully ranked

Tags: regression, compositional-data

I am running a linear regression model with about 5000 cases. The dependent variable is income at closure an interval variable. I have run this model without problem many times. Now I am adding 9 new variables required by the federal government. There are actually 10 they require I left one out. All of these variables have 4 distinct levels, they are the percent in an occupation for a given quarter. When I run the model with 3 of the occupation variables there is no problem, when I run 4 or more I get the model is not full rank, you can predict the variables from other variables. It does not matter which of the occupation variables I add nor which are the original 3, I always get this error. And when I manually calculate the results shown I don't actually get the value they say I should. I am completely baffled.[image]

Comment: The fourth variable is completely determined by the other three because they must add to 100%.

Comment: I wanted to follow up on the comment The percentages add up to 100 percent withing a single variable.  For example, construction (var1) and education (var2). Each of the two vars add up to 100 percent, but if you are in one of these jobs you are not in the other (maybe that is what is meant although the model runs with 3 variables each of which add up to 100 percent).  A more basic issue is, how do I run the regression, because I have to use all these 9 variables (it must be possible because the department of labor has run them for years). Thanks for the help.

Comment: You aren't forced to use redundant variables.  Because your model also includes the equivalent of a constant, you lose no information by dropping one out of each group of sum-to-100 percent variables: that's what the error message is trying to tell you.

Comment: I was wrong about my previous comments. The 4 quarters for any given variable do not sum up to 100 percent. They show how the percent in a given job for that variable of the total workforce. Nor do the  set of 10 variables sum to 100 percent (because these 10 variables are a subset of the total set of jobs that exist). So the problem continues.

Comment: It has a comparable resolution, though: the software is telling you it is mathematically impossible to assign definite coefficients to all variables because some of them are completely determined as linear combinations of the others.  You can read a lot about this situation and the various options in other threads: use regression, multicollinearity, and rank for keywords and then narrow your search based on what you find.

Comment: thanks. I will. In all the years I have run regression this only happened twice (and the first I found the error).